# Is Direct file path access fully supported in Android 11?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a feature implementation which fully relies on Direct File path access to iterate over files and read files.

Note that the feature only access Shared storage files (not App specific files of other apps).

So according to Google, File API and direct file path access are deprecated in Android 10 and brought back in Android 11.

*So, I kept the implementation as is, set `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` as `30` (Android 11), set `requestLegacyExternalStorage` as true and uploaded it to Internal App sharing.
When I tested it on Android 10 and 11, its working with no problems.*

My questions -

**Is scoped storage implementation not necessary for Android 11?**

**Will my feature break if I publish to production?**

**If direct file path access works as is, what is the use of MANAGEMANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? (Ability to access app specific files on External storage?)**

As I have to target API 30 by  November 1st, wanted to confirm this.

**UPDATE: More about what the feature does.**

1. Has a directory path stored in Preferences (Can be changed by user) (*Path -  /storage/emulated/0/SomeFolder/*)
2. On triggering the function (input is some date time epoch). It will iterate over all the files in the directory (that we have in preferences), checks its last modified time and if it closer to input time, returns the file path. (The files in the directory are created by other app on the phone.)
3. The file path is then used to upload the file to server.

Comment: Are you talking about `requestLegacyExternalStorage`? If your app is targeting Android 11 and you run it on Android 11, then that flag is ignored by the system. We don't know how your app behaves if it can't access certain files/directories, or exactly what you have been testing, so it's not really possible to say how this will affect you.

Comment: `Is scoped storage implementation not necessary for Android 11?` You cannot implement scoped storage as it is not somerhing that was added to storage possibilities. In fact it brings no new features. Scoped storage is only a restrction on the things that earlier were possible. You can do less now.

Comment: You should begin with telling better about your feature. As now we dont know what you need.

Comment: `which fully relies on Direct File path` Direct? Did you invent that naming? Better: `which fully relies on accessing external storage with file paths`.

Comment: @blackapps I did not invent the term. The docs refers to it as such (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#direct-file-paths). Regardless of terminology, I just mean accessing file using its path rather than Uri.

Comment: @Michael Yes thats the flag I am referring to (sorry mistyped). Also added more details about what the feature does. Let me if more details are needed.

Comment: I wonder why you did not  tell full parh of your directory. And before you can iterate over files you should first list them. Mostly on Android 11 there is a problem with listing but you are not even mentioning listing. Further you did not tell which app created those files.

Comment: @blackapps Added more details.

Comment: Your app on an Android 11 device will not be able to list files of other apps in that directory. Maybe some media files. That's all. (Again you are not mentioning listing). And that your app could not list those files you could have told us.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238315/discussion-between-susheel-karam-and-blackapps).

Comment: Sorry, no chatting.